# PyQt QtWebEngine открытие сайта в поиске яндекса

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside6, qtwebengine, яндекс-поиск

При нажатии на ссылку в `гугл`, сайт загружается корректно в этом же окне, 
а при открытии через `яндекс` ничего не происходит

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Код у меня большой поэтому вот пример из документации:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLineEdit,
    QMainWindow, QPushButton, QToolBar)
from PySide6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEnginePage
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('PySide6 WebEngineWidgets Example')

        self.toolBar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(self.toolBar)
        self.backButton = QPushButton()
        self.backButton.setIcon(QIcon(':/qt-project.org/styles/commonstyle/images/left-32.png'))
        self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.back)
        self.toolBar.addWidget(self.backButton)
        self.forwardButton = QPushButton()
        self.forwardButton.setIcon(QIcon(':/qt-project.org/styles/commonstyle/images/right-32.png'))
        self.forwardButton.clicked.connect(self.forward)
        self.toolBar.addWidget(self.forwardButton)

        self.addressLineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.addressLineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.load)
        self.toolBar.addWidget(self.addressLineEdit)

        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.webEngineView)
        initialUrl = 'http://yandex.ru'
        self.addressLineEdit.setText(initialUrl)
        self.webEngineView.load(QUrl(initialUrl))
        self.webEngineView.page().titleChanged.connect(self.setWindowTitle)
        self.webEngineView.page().urlChanged.connect(self.urlChanged)

    def load(self):
        url = QUrl.fromUserInput(self.addressLineEdit.text())
        if url.isValid():
            self.webEngineView.load(url)

    def back(self):
        self.webEngineView.page().triggerAction(QWebEnginePage.Back)

    def forward(self):
        self.webEngineView.page().triggerAction(QWebEnginePage.Forward)

    def urlChanged(self, url):
        self.addressLineEdit.setText(url.toString())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    availableGeometry = mainWin.screen().availableGeometry()
    mainWin.resize(availableGeometry.width() * 2 / 3, availableGeometry.height() * 2 / 3)
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, код

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: а что происходит в https://www.bing.com/

Comment: такая же проблема, что и в яндексе

Comment: ну смотрите, яндекс у меня не доступен, а в bing раз зайду показывает, а при другом заходе не показывает.

Comment: хотите сказать, что bing через раз загружает страницу?

Comment: да, но еще раз - это происходит при новом входе в приложении.

Comment: у меня вообще никак не загружается, только гугл

Comment: и ещё в логах это: "js: The resource https://www.bing.com/th?id... was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

гоголь загружает линки в то же окно, а яндекс пытается открыть его в новой вкладке (target="_blank"). Ваш виджет пытается получить это новое окно, в которое загрузит результат. Ему в этом надо немного помочь, реализовав "создание вкладки браузера":

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLineEdit,
    QMainWindow, QPushButton, QToolBar)
from PySide6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEnginePage
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class myWebView(QWebEngineView):
    def createWindow(self, type_):
        if type_ == QWebEnginePage.WebWindowType.WebBrowserTab:
            return self # говорим чтобы грузил в то же окно. (или можем создать новый виджет и грузить в него)  

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('PySide6 WebEngineWidgets Example')

        self.toolBar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(self.toolBar)
        self.addressLineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.toolBar.addWidget(self.addressLineEdit)

        self.webEngineView = myWebView() #QWebEngineView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.webEngineView)
        initialUrl = 'https://yandex.ru'
        self.addressLineEdit.setText(initialUrl)
        self.webEngineView.load(QUrl(initialUrl))
        self.webEngineView.page().titleChanged.connect(self.setWindowTitle)
        self.webEngineView.page().urlChanged.connect(self.urlChanged)

    def urlChanged(self, url):
        self.addressLineEdit.setText(url.toString())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    availableGeometry = mainWin.screen().availableGeometry()
    mainWin.resize(availableGeometry.width() * 2 / 3, availableGeometry.height() * 2 / 3)
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Можете посмотреть пример, в котором создаются дополнительные вкладки в tabview [по этой ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66350233/how-to-open-hyperlink-with-target-blank-in-pyqtwebengine)